# limiting joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_n\xrightarrow[d]{}N(0,\sigma^2_x)$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow[d]{}N(0,\sigma^2_y)$.

$X_n, Y_n$ are not independent.

Can I say that $\left( \begin{array} {}
X_n \\
Y_n \end{array} \right)\xrightarrow[d]{}N(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{C})$, with $\mathbf{C}$ a variance-covariance matrix?

Would $\mathbf{C}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma^2_x & \lim Cov(X_n,Y_n)  \\
\lim Cov(Y_n,X_n) & \sigma^2_y \end{array} \right)$ ?

Comment: [No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for your interest in this question.
I'm still having some doubts on how the wiki article you posted above, with the title «Normally distributed and uncorrelated does not imply independent» helps my case...
Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Let all $X_n$ equal wiki's $X$, all $Y_n$ equal wiki's $Y$. Then $(X,Y)$ (the limit) is not jointly normal.

Comment: @ And what if they were independent?

Comment: Then the answer is affirmative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no because if $X,Y$ are not independent, they can be jointly non-normal distributed.

That is because dependency implies a Copula function $c$. Only for the Gaussian Copula or Independence Copula, the joint distribution is Normal aswell:

$$f(x,y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)\cdot c\left(F^{-1}(x),F^{-1}(y)\right)$$

For example, using an asymmetric Copula, such as Gumbel Copula, would result in an asymmetric joint distribution, hence non-normal.